# Does componentDidUpdate run after all children have been updated?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know if a React component's lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` gets executed after all of the children's `render` methods have finished, or right after the `render` method for that component is called.

Since the reconciler recursively calls `render` method to update the view, I have a hunch that `componentDidUpdate` gets executed after all children of a component has been re-rendered, but there was not enough information in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). When exactly is `componentDidUpdate` called?

Comment: Add some logging to the parent `componentDidUpdate` method and add some the the `render` methods of the children, see which one is output first.

Comment: lifecyle methods are called for children first, then parents

Comment: Right but is this documented officially anywhere? Is this subject to change?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `componentDidUpdate` method is called after the `render` method of the component is done executing. That means that it will be called after all children's `render` methods have finished. This is implied in the documentation you linked:

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM **when the component has been updated.**

The component is only updated post-render, so the documentation implies that it's called after all children, and consequently the parent, have finished rerendering (albeit [a bit unclear](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2796)). You can only really operate on the DOM when it finishes updating, children and all.

For example, say we have two components, `A` and `B` and `B` renders a `A` component. `componentDidUpdate` for `B` will only be called once `B`'s `render` finishes. The `render` of `B` will finish after `A`'s `render` is successfully called because children are rendered first due to being part of the parent. That means the answer to your question is: `componentDidUpdate` is executed after all the children's `render`s have completed.

Comment: For those looking for the official docs: [React.Component - Updating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)

Comment: It seems that `componentDidUpdate` is called after all children `render`, but cannot guaranteed after the UI updated really, eg: DOM changes, or view changed in react-native

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if there is more in-depth documentation somewhere, but it is indeed easy enough to test on your own.

```
class Nested extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {foo: undefined};
  }
  render() {
    console.log("Rendered " + this.props.name);
    return <div><button onClick={() => {this.setState({foo: Date.now()})}}>Update {this.props.name}</button>{this.props.children ? React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {foo: this.state.foo}) : undefined}</div>
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Updated " + this.props.name);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Nested name="outer"><Nested name="inner"></Nested></Nested>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

http://jsbin.com/yiyuhegayo/edit?js,console,output

Updating the outer component results in the innermost `componentDidUpdate` running first, and then the outermost. Updating the inner component only causes that component to update.

Interestingly, it is the opposite for the `render` functions. The outer component renders first, then the inner one.

Comment: you're logging render at the start of the render method. The inner render will finish before the outer one does.

Comment: @AndyRay Good point. But I guess there's no other way to do it, since you can't log *after* the render function returns.

Comment: But you can write:
    ```render() {
    console.log("Start rendering " + this.props.name);
    const retVal = <div><button onClick={() => {this.setState({foo: Date.now()})}}>Update {this.props.name}</button>{this.props.children ? React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {foo: this.state.foo}) : undefined}</div>;
    console.log("End rendering " + this.props.name);
    return retVal;
  }```

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Li correctly pointed out, `componentDidUpdate` is executed after all children have been rendered. While this still stands, since then, React's Fiber reconciliation algorithm (version 16.0 onwards) may have changed previous assumptions.

In a nutshell, React divides the work into two phases, the `render` (executed first) phase and the `commit` (executed after `render`) phase. `componentDidUpdate` falls under the `commit` phase and is the last lifecycle method called in this phase (after `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount`) and will therefore always occur after the rendering of a node and its children.

The `render` phase traverses the Fiber tree as a "depth-first" traversal as illustrated in this image (taken from the highly recommended [Inside Fiber: in-depth overview of the new reconciliation algorithm in React](https://indepth.dev/inside-fiber-in-depth-overview-of-the-new-reconciliation-algorithm-in-react/)).

(child nodes are illustrated horizontally, so `c1` is a child of `b2` and `b3` is a sibling node of `b2`, while `b1` doesn't have any children.)

[image: Inside Fiber: in-depth overview of the new reconciliation algorithm in React]

Additionally, a component may re-render (for example, following a state change, HOC, connected props...etc) and this will not trigger a `componentDidUpdate` on the parent. I think this was always the case, even before v16.0.

With the above being said, I believe it is unusual (and possibly unsafe) to make assumptions on the rendering of child components and would create unnecessary coupling between these components and recommend that each component is modular enough to not depend on its parent's `componentDidUpdate` or its child's `render()`. If you need to inform a parent that a child(ren) has finished rendering, you may pass a function as a prop which is then called inside `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` (or `useEffect`).

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-rendering-tr59s