# React: How can we know that all component has been mounted/rendered after setState()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In react a call to a component (`R`) 's `setState()` can trigger the re-render of all child components.

How can we know when that has finished ? 
Which lifecycle method is called after all the children of `R` have been mounted/rendered/updated ?

**In more detail:**

Let's consider the following situation:

There is a root component `R`, and its child components `C1` and `C2`.

I would like to implement my own redux store where child components ( `C1` and `C2`) can dispatch actions and AFTER all the children have been mounted/re-rendered/updated I would like to command the redux store to process the dispatched actions.

So I would need to know when all children have been rendered and schedule a call to the redux store that will command the store to process the dispatched actions.

Which lifecycle method is called after `R`'s all children have been mounted/rendered/updated ?

Comment: check `componentdidupdate`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle event. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

It is triggered when the component is being updated (and that all its children are updated too).

⚠ this event is not triggered on the very first render. If you also need to handle to first render, you will have to use both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 13):

**Update**: React has changed its lifecycle but in this case the method you need it's still the same. The new lifecycle is:

A) Mounting

1. constructor
2. static getDerivedStateFromProps
3. render
4. componentDidMount

B) Updating (includes both, props and state)

1. static getDerivedStateFromProps
2. shouldComponentUpdate
3. render
4. getSnapshotBeforeUpdate
5. **componentDidUpdate**

---

OLD ANSWER

`ComponentDidUpdate` will do what you say. It is launched right after a render because of props changes or a render because of state changes.

Life Cycle:

A) Mounting

1. Constructor
2. ComponentWillMount
3. Render
4. ComponentDidMount

B) Props Changes

1. ComponentWillReceiveProps
2. ShouldComponentUpdate
3. Render
4. **ComponentDidUpdate**

C) State Changes

1. ShouldComponentUpdate
2. ComponentWillUpdate
3. Render
4. **ComponentDidUpdate**

More information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Thanks, but will it launch after all children have been rendered?

Comment: Yes. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916045/does-componentdidupdate-run-after-all-children-have-been-updated

Comment: I am not sure about it. The guy's response is just a deduction of the current documentation **which specifies that `componentDidUpdate` is called when DOM is updated** but ***doesn't imply that for its own children***. I want to highlight that these kind of operations are asynchronous

Comment: The father component render isn't finished until all it's children are rendered. So if the father's render process isn't finished, it's componentDidUpdate isn't launched. In any case, testing this and confirming this behavior isn't tedious to do.