# React - componentDidUpdate() is unable to find DOM objects rendered by the render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit:** I've edited the code to add and use refs instead of `document.getElementById`. It didn't fix the problem.

**Edit 2:** So I did a bit of testing with `mutationObserver`, and it turns out that `componentDidUpdate()` starts executing about 100 milliseconds **before** the nodes are actually inserted! This is definitely the problem.

However, the React docs say that `componentDidUpdate()` only fires after `render()` is completely done executing? Am I missing something here? If so, what? All I want is for my code to execute **after** all nodes from `render()` have been inserted.

**Edit 3:** The issue has been found and fixed. Refer the answer I posted below. Thanks to everyone who helped.

---

So I'm trying to create a sign-in dialog for my website. I'm utilizing React to build the dialog and FirebaseUI to show the content. My problem is that after React renders the DOM nodes via the `render()` method on state change (from `open: false` to`open: true`), the `componentDidUpdate()` function is unable to find these DOM nodes immediately.

```
class SignInModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dialogTitle = React.createRef();
    this.firebaseContainer = React.createRef();
  }
  state = {
    open: false,
    redirect: null,
    preRedirectFunction: null,
  };

  handleClickOpen = (redirect, preRedirectFunction) => {    

    this.setState({
      open: true,
      redirect: redirect,
      preRedirectFunction: preRedirectFunction,
    });

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate at time: ");
    console.log(Date.now());
    console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log("Dialog title: ")
    console.log(this.dialogTitle.current);
    console.log("Firebase container: ")
    console.log(this.firebaseContainer.current);

    /* setTimeout(function () {
      var authUI = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
    if(authUI){
      console.log("AuthUI found");
      authUI.reset();
      authUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', getUIConfig(authUI, SignInModalRendered.state.redirect,SignInModalRendered.state.preRedirectFunction));
    }
    else{
      console.log("No AuthUI found");
      startFirebaseUI("", SignInModalRendered.state.preRedirectFunction);
    }
    }, 200); */


  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      redirect: null,
      preRedirectFunction: null,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering sign-in modal");
    console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log("Dialog title: ")
    console.log(this.dialogTitle.current);
    console.log("Firebase container: ")
    console.log(this.firebaseContainer.current);
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" ref={this.dialogTitle} onClose={this.handleClose} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          {Date.now()}
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent id="SignInDialogContainer">
            <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" ref={this.firebaseContainer}></div>
            <div id="loader">{Date.now()}</div>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

<strike>When this code is executed, the code fails on the line `authUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container'....` as it is unable to find the DOM node.</strike>

With the edited code, I'm trying purely to get the console logs inside `componentDidUpdate()` to be able to find the Dialog Title and Firebase Container DOM nodes. They still return `null`.

[Date.now() within the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykOfH.png)

[Console log showing the Date.now()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gwms.png)

<strike>However, the output of the `Date.now()` functions in the DOM and the `componentDidUpdate()` function (as per above images) shows that the code within `componentDidUpdate()` is being executed 2 milliseconds after the DOM is rendered. So why is the line of code within `componentDidUpdate()` unable to find it?</strike>

I've figured out that `componentDidUpdate()` is executing about 100 milliseconds **before** the nodes are done rendering. Why is this so? And how do I get my code to execute **after** the nodes are done rendering?

**Additional info :** I tried putting the offending code block inside a `setTimeout` function with a 200ms delay and it runs perfectly. But I don't want to use this workaround, I want to understand what's happening.

Comment: How about using refs instead of this to interact with the DOM?

Comment: Yes. The `ref` attribute is your best friend here. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to React and don't understand what you're trying to tell me, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Okay, so I should use refs instead of the `id` property?

Comment: Yes. Refs are the way forward if you need to interact with browser DOM. `getElementById`, not so good.

Comment: Okay so I added the refs and am now using the refs instead of `document.getElementById` in the console log statements in `componentDidUpdate()`. There has been no change in the console output. It's still not able to find the DOM nodes.

Comment: where is `authUI` coming from? is it yours or some 3rd party? while it expects string with CSS selector it's impossible just to replace that with `ref`

Comment: `authUI` is part of the Firebase library which I've integrated. In any case I've commented that entire block out and I'm focusing purely on the console log statements that are to find the Dialog Title and FIrebase Container. The issue is that those statements are returning `null` (because `componentDidUpdate()` is unable to find those DOM nodes).

Comment: you're misinterpreting the data: `<div id="loader">{Date.now()}</div>` this date here has nothing to do with the time when a node was inserted into DOM.

Comment: Oh? What time is it actually capturing then? Is it at all possible that the code within `componentDidUpdate()` starts to execute before the DOM is actually rendered by `render()`? That would explain a lot

Comment: you can use `mutationObserver` to shed some light onto when a node is inserted

Comment: So I did a bit of testing with `mutationObserver`, and it turns out that `componentDidUpdate()` starts executing about 100 milliseconds **before** the nodes are actually inserted! This is definitely the problem. 

However, the React docs say that `componentDidUpdate()` only fires after `render()` is completely done executing? Am I missing something here? If so, what? All I want is for my code to execute **after** all nodes from `render()` have been inserted.

Comment: in react there are two different actions: rendering and commiting. rendering is when `render()` functions are executed creating React element tree and commiting is when changes are being made into the DOM. AFAIK `componentDidUpdate` is called after commiting so the problem might be with `<Dialog>` not rendering children immediately when `open` is `true` but doing some other work.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. Wouldn't have been able to do it without you telling me about me misinterpreting the data initially. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with a little help from [marzelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5664434/marzelin), who pointed me in the right direction, I managed to figure out why `componentDidUpdate()` was unable to find the DOM element.

The short answer is, in fact, that the DOM element simply did not exist at the time the code was executed.

I was perplexed as to why `componentDidUpdate()` was firing before `render()` finished rendering all the DOM elements inside it. Then, reading [an answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916153/12200477), I realized that `componentDidUpdate()` fires **when the outermost element inside the `render()` function is rendered**, without waiting for the inner elements to finish rendering.

I then replaced the DOM element which I needed to operate on, with a new React class which consisted of **only that element**, and I put my code inside the `componentDidMount()` method of the new class.

This solved my problem.

My new and updated code:

```
class FirebaseContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){ 
    super(props);
    console.log("Passed props: ");
    console.log(props);
    this.firebaseContainer = React.createRef();    
  }

  state = this.props.parentState;  

componentDidMount() {
  console.log("componentDidMount at time: ");
  console.log(Date.now());
  /* console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
  console.log(this.state); */

  console.log("Firebase container: ")
  console.log(this.firebaseContainer.current);

  var authUI = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
  if(authUI){
    console.log("AuthUI found");
    authUI.reset();
    authUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', getUIConfig(authUI, this.state.redirect,this.state.preRedirectFunction));
  }
  else{
    console.log("No AuthUI found");
    startFirebaseUI("", this.state.preRedirectFunction);
  } 
}

  render(){
    console.log("Rendering Firebase container");
    console.log("Firebase container state: ")
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log("Dialog title: ")
    console.log(document.getElementById('customized-dialog-title'));
    console.log("Firebase container: ")
    console.log(document.getElementById('firebaseui-auth-container'));
    return(
      <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" ref={this.firebaseContainer}></div>
    );
  }
}

class SignInModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dialogTitle = React.createRef();
  }
  state = {
    open: false,
    redirect: null,
    preRedirectFunction: null,
  };

  handleClickOpen = (redirect, preRedirectFunction) => {    

    this.setState({
      open: true,
      redirect: redirect,
      preRedirectFunction: preRedirectFunction,
    });

  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      redirect: null,
      preRedirectFunction: null,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering sign-in modal");
    console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <Dialog ref={this.dialogTitle}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={this.handleClose} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
            Please sign in
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent id="SignInDialogContainer">
            <FirebaseContainer parentState={this.state}/>
            <div id="loader">{Date.now()}</div>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue but instead of one dom element, I have a list of children dom nodes and I need to know when all children UI has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the refs in the constructor. Ex: `this.refName = React.createRef();`

Assign the ref as a prop in the component `<Component ref={this.refName} />`

Access the refs with `this.refName.current`

```
class SignInModal extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.customizedDialogTitle = React.createRef();
    this.signInDialogContainer = React.createRef();
    this.firebaseuiAuthContainer = React.createRef();
    this.loader = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      redirect: null,
      preRedirectFunction: null,
    }
  }

  handleClickOpen = (redirect, preRedirectFunction) => {

    this.setState({
      open: true,
      redirect: redirect,
      preRedirectFunction: preRedirectFunction,
    });

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate at time: ");
    console.log(Date.now());
    console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log("Dialog title: ")
    console.log(this.customizedDialogTitle.current);
    console.log("Firebase container: ")
    console.log(this.firebaseuiAuthContainer.current);

    var authUI = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
    if(authUI){
      console.log("AuthUI found");
      authUI.reset();
      authUI.start('#firebaseuiAuthContainer', getUIConfig(authUI, this.state.redirect,this.state.preRedirectFunction));
    }
    else{
      console.log("No AuthUI found");
      startFirebaseUI("", this.state.preRedirectFunction);
    }
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      redirect: null,
      preRedirectFunction: null,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering sign-in modal");
    console.log("Sign in modal state: ")
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log("Dialog title: ")
    console.log(this.customizedDialogTitle.current);
    console.log("Firebase container: ")
    console.log(this.firebaseuiAuthContainer.current);
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          <DialogTitle ref={this.customizedDialogTitle} id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={this.handleClose} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          {Date.now()}
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent ref={this.signInDialogContainer}>
            <div ref={this.firebaseuiAuthContainer}></div>
            <div ref={this.loader}>{Date.now()}</div>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did pretty much this as per the comments on my question. The issue remains the same, the console logs still show `null` for the Dialog Title and Firebase Container.